# find position of element - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I try to find the position of an arbitrary element inside an angular directive.

My idea was to add a class with ng-class and then use `element[0].querySelector('.theClass').getBoundingClientRect();` to get the position.

The error is: `Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null`.

So my suspect is, that the template of the directive is not compiled yet, such that querySelector can not find it.

So I also tried `$timeout(function(){ ... })`, but with the same result.

Any ideas how to find the position of an arbitrary element in angular?

The code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'the/template',
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        objects:"="
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {   
        $timeout(function(){
            //DOM has finished rendering
            var rect = element[0].querySelector('.theClass').getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log('this is the element');
            console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

And the template is about:

```
<span ng-repeat="object in objects">
   <span ng-class="{'theClass':$last}"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Could you post the code of the directive ?

Comment: I added some code. Hope its correct, since I removed everything except for the code in question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to put it in postLink like :

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'the/template',
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        objects:"="
      },
      link: {
            post : function (scope, element, attrs) {   

               var rect = element[0].querySelector('.theClass').getBoundingClientRect();
               console.log('this is the element');
               console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
            }
       }
     };
  });
```

Comment: I wasnt aware of this. The default is pre? But it gives the same result.